# Dereferencing a void pointer using its size in C

Tags: c

I know that we cannot dereference a void pointer until and unless we typecast it.

```
void *ptr = call_a_function();
printf("%d",*(int *)ptr);
```

This informs the datatype of element(in this case its integer) to the compiler so that it can dereference the amount of space required for it(in this case  its 4 bytes).

Suppose I dont know the final datatype, however I know the size of datatype. Can I still dereference it using only the size(4 bytes) and not the datatype(not using int)??

In other words is there a way to tell the compiler how many bytes of memory to read by providing the number of bytes to extract and not the datatype??

**EDIT** -

I needed to swap the contents of two void * pointers.

Got influenced by the regular way of swapping two values i.e storing the value of one pointer in a temporary variable and then proceed with swapping.

Was trying to attempt the same thing without knowing the datatype but only its size( since the function with this swap code accepts size of variable as one parameter ). However after reading the answers and comments, got to realize that I really dont need to dereference it. Probably `memcpy` is the correct way to go.

Comment: Dereferencing by itself like `*p;` doesn't really do anything. What exactly are you going to do with the dereferenced pointer? Assign it to something else? Assign something else to it? The compiler needs to know the type to generate appropriate code.

Comment: You could `memcpy` the data wherever your void pointer is pointing into a variable. Not sure if that helps...

Comment: What will help you to dereference a void pointer? You usually can't tell how big it is unless its a char pointer and it ends with a \0.  You can tell the system to extract n bytes with the memcpy and memset actions, but you don't need to dereference to do that.

Comment: You can use the fixed-size datatypes defined in `<stdint.h>`. E.g. the four byte datatype is `uint32_t`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to give a meaningful answer to this question without knowing what you want to _do_ with the data.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I dont know the final datatype, however I know the size of datatype. Can I still dereference it using only the size(4 bytes) and not the datatype(not using int)??

Since you cannot deduce or assume the data type, you can't dereference the pointer once to get the complete object. However, you can extract each byte and use it anyway you want.

```
void *ptr = call_a_function();
unsigned char* cptr = (unsigned char*)ptr;
for (int i = 0; i < num_bytes; ++i )
{
   unsigned char c = cptr[i];
   // Use c
}
```

Comment: `unsigned char` would have some advantages with unknown data of an unknown source type..

Comment: @chux, I tend to agree with you. Some think that it makes no difference for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the whole is not the sum of its parts. Casting not only provides the compiler with the size of the data but also how that data is to be interpreted. Suppose you get 4 bytes, this could be a string of three characters with a NULL byte or a signed integer, which could be encoded in big-endian or little-endian depending on the platform. So knowing the size is not sufficient to properly handle the data even if you could tell the compiler how many bytes to read/dereference.